# Lucene search using TermQuery only works with WhitespaceAnalyzer but not StandardAnalyzer

Tags: java, lucene

I trying to test searching on Lucene using `TermQuery`. However, it seems the search only works if I use `WhitespaceAnalyzer`. As soon as I switched to `StandardAnalyzer`, the test failed.

Here are the tests:

```
 @Test
    public void simpleTermSearch() throws Exception {
        Directory testDirectory = new RAMDirectory();
        IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(LUCENE_36, new StandardAnalyzer(LUCENE_36));
        IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(testDirectory, config);

        Document document = new Document();
        document.add(new Field("id", "001", Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
        document.add(new Field("priority", "HIGH", Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
        document.add(new Field("assignee", "Genzer Hawker", Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

        indexWriter.updateDocument(new Term("id", "111"), document);

        IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(IndexReader.open(indexWriter, true));
        Term priority = new Term("priority", "HIGH");
        TermQuery termQuery = new TermQuery(priority);
        TopDocs topDocs = indexSearcher.search(termQuery, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        assertEquals(1, topDocs.scoreDocs.length);
    }
```

What puzzles me is that the values are so simple so I think there will be no different whether I use `WhitespaceAnalyzer` or `StandardAnalyzer` but it seems I miss something. I use lucene-core-3.6.0.

Could you help me to understand how it works like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is case sensitivity.

`StandardTokenizer` includes a `LowercaseFilter`.  `WhitespaceAnalyzer` does not.  So, using `StandardTokenizer` your priority is indexed as "high", whereas it's indexed as "HIGH" by `WhitespaceAnalyzer`.

This wouldn't be an issue for your query if it were being analyzed (ie. using a QueryParser), but there isn't going to be any analysis of your `TermQuery`.  Try changing your query to:

```
TermQuery termQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("priority", "high"));
```

To see that in action.

Comment: I also discovered it myself. Another approach (which I used) is to use `QueryParser` and the same `Analyzer` which I used to index the field. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

femtoRgon has correctly pointed out the problem and his solution was the first thing I used. However, there was another approach and it was my final solution. Therefore I added this answer for those who is interested.

My approach was to use `QueryParser` to create `Query` instead of manually making `TermQuery`.

`QueryParser` requires an `Analyzer` so you just need to give it the same `Analyzer` you use to index.

```
 @Test
    public void simpleTermSearch() throws Exception {
        Directory testDirectory = new RAMDirectory();
        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(LUCENE_36);

        IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(LUCENE_36, analyzer);
        IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(testDirectory, config);

        Document document = new Document();
        document.add(new Field("id", "001", Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
        document.add(new Field("priority", "HIGH", Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
        document.add(new Field("assignee", "Genzer Hawker", Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

        indexWriter.add(document);

        //Term priority = new Term("priority", "HIGH");
        //TermQuery termQuery = new TermQuery(priority);
        Query query = new QueryParser(LUCENE_36, "priority", analyzer).parse("HIGH");

        IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(IndexReader.open(indexWriter, true));
        TopDocs topDocs = indexSearcher.search(query, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        assertEquals(1, topDocs.scoreDocs.length);
    }
```